# Rails controller renders JSON in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a simple controller that I have responding to both `html` and `json`. I'm using the `json` response for a Backbone app. Everything works as expected, except that when I click a link that uses the `show` method, and then click the back button, the `index` method just prints a big string of `JSON` into the browser. If I refresh, it displays HTML as expected. Here's the controller.

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @recipes = Recipe.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: Recipe.where(user_id: params[:user_id]).featured }
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

I tried adding a check for `response.xhr?`, and only rendering `JSON` if it was an AJAX request, but that didn't work.

#### Edit

This is a Rails 3 app not utilizing turbolinks.

#### Edit 2

Here is the relevant Backbone code.

```
# app/assets/javascripts/collections/recipe_list_.js.cofee
@App.Collections.RecipeList = Backbone.Collection.extend
  url: ->
    "/users/#{@userId}/recipes"
  model: window.App.Models.Recipe
  initialize: (opts) ->
    @userId = opts.userId


# app/assets/javascripts/app.js.coffee
$ ->
  urlAry = window.location.href.split('/')
  userId = urlAry[urlAry.length - 2]
  App = window.App
  App.recipeList = new App.Collections.RecipeList(userId: userId)
  App.recipeListView = new App.Views.RecipeListView
```

Comment: The index action is not actually hit when you click the back button in your browser. The browser will show what's in it's cache instead. The problem is on the client side, not the server.

Comment: That had actually crossed my mind. Any idea how to deal with it? Anything to force a re-render?

Comment: This happened to me while I was doing a demo today, I do a lot of partial loading and this is a big issue.

Comment: Problem is on client side. Can you post the code ?

Comment: @shiva Posted what seems relevant. Please let me know if you need more.

Comment: For anyone that finds this via Google, I added a `before_filter` to my `ApplicationController` with `Vary=Accept` headers. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17163778/931934). This is what ultimately worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try using /recipes.html
and /recipes.json
and /recipes/1.html and /recipes/1.json

instead of relying on backbone and history to always send the correct headers

Comment: This fixed the issue. The bounty expired, so I wasn't able to award points to this. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

If you're referring to a chrome and turbolinks issue, then an easy fix is to disable caching on ajax requests:

`$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})`

Comment: i haven't, but because of the answer which got the bounty, which talks about turbolinks, i thought i misunderstood and that turbolinks is involved somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I bet it's due to turbolink, or ajax based page rendering (backbone, `remote=true`, ...)

I always disable turbolink and keep control over which links are `remote=true`, and for all ajax response I insert this javascript line at the end

```
history.pushState(null, '', '/the/requested/url' );
```

If you don't want to manually implement this line for each of your link responses, you can wrap it in an `ajax:complete` event ([more info](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax)), and I assume turbolink has an event you can use as well.

Second part of the trick is to bind `popstate` so when your users click on the "back" button the page will be refreshed from the server (through the url that was *pushState*-ed earlier) and the ajax/js/json/whatever response won't be displayed anymore.

```
setTimeout( function () {
  $(window).bind('popstate', function () {
    window.location = location.href;
  });
}, 500);
```

As you see I wrap the popstate event binding in a `setTimeout`, because if you don't do that you may have trouble with some browser that would infinitely refresh the page.

Comment: Some good suggestions, but binding to `popstate` feels a little hacky. It's Rails 3, so no turbolinks, and `remote=true` isn't anywhere in my repo.

Comment: It's not a hack, it's browser history control. Anyhow if you don't like it, keep looking then and good luck

Comment: I see you are using backbone, my answer still applies

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Chrome?  if so this is a known issue. When you hit the back button chromes serves the page from cache since what was returned was json that is what it dumps on the screen. This post has some suggested workarounds

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108766